# Partition function of an asteroid gas (gravity)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, singularities, partition-function

Consider the classical problem (Newtonian gravity) of a large number of $N$ identical non-interacting asteroids orbiting around a big planet. I wanted to see if the problem was solvable. I wrote my Hamiltonian:

$$H=\frac{p_r^2}{2m}+\frac{p_\theta^2}{2mr^2}+\frac{p_\varphi^2}{2mr^2\sin^2(\theta)}-\frac{GmM}{r}$$

But calculating the partition function I get:
$$Z=C\int r^2e^{\beta GmM/r}\mathrm{d}r$$ (where $C$ is a constant dependent of $\beta,m$).

Sadly, this integral does not converge in any of this ranges [($0,\infty$) or ($r_0,\infty$)].

I suppose it the divergence is similar to the one in quantum case (see [partition function of the hydrogen gas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4394/)).

Is this a clue to some physics missing (asteroid-asteroid interactions, relativity)? Is the solution to regularize also?

Any papers, books, or references that treat this case (specially a classical gas) are welcomed.

Comment: Perhaps this problem has some analogy to the Boltzmann statistics of a planet's atmosphere (a discussion of such a problem is present here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/436036/).